# URI of a preference of my own application?

Tags: android, uri, preferences

For my android application I store a preference, lets call it "test_preference". Now I need the URI of this preference, so I can set up a ContentObserver for this preference. But how do I get the URI? For android system settings there's Settings.System.getUriFor(String name), but what do I have to use to get the URI of the preferences of my own application? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to observe changes of this preference in your own application, just use [`SharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29). If you want to observe changes of this preference outside your application, then your should implement it yourself via custom `ContentProvider`. There is no such functionality out of the box.

---

If you read [documentaion of `SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.